# Add class to similar elements after click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add class to DIV after click on A with the same class. For example

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#1" class="test1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#2" class="test2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#3" class="test3">3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="test">
<div class="test1">test1</div>
<div class="test2">test2</div>
<div class="test3">test3</div>
</div>
```

If I click on a.test1 I need add class ACTIVE to this a and div.test1
I did this simple code for A but I don't know what I should do for DIV

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('ul li').click(function() {
        jQuery("li.active").removeClass("active");
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    });
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the related `div` element by matching the `index` of the clicked `li`. Try this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('ul li').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('.test div').eq(index).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
})
```

```css
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#1" class="test1">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2" class="test2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#3" class="test3">3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="test">
  <div class="test1">test1</div>
  <div class="test2">test2</div>
  <div class="test3">test3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! That's what I need! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code works,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('ul li').click(function() {
        jQuery("li.active").removeClass("active");
        var divClass = jQuery(this).attr("class"); 
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');

        jQuery("div.active").removeClass('active');
        jQuery("div."+divClass).addClass('active');
    });
})
```